# Using sqlite3 and tkinter i have made this small inventory management system, the problem is the entry to the database is always null

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

The code does not add new elements instead adds blank values to the database. Confused!

```
def ProEntry():
        def makeEntry(name,date,dept,amt,amt2,lab,thr):
            conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO products VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(name.get(), date.get(), dept.get(), amt.get(), amt2.get(), lab.get(), thr.get()))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
```

From here I begin adding values to the gui using entry widget

```
    entrywindow = Tk()
    entrywindow.title("New Product Entry")
    namedisp = Label(entrywindow, text="Name Of Product").grid(row=0, column=0)
    name = StringVar()
    nameentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=name).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

To check individual variables I printed name using name.get() but that also outputs null value.

```
    print(name.get())

    datedisp = Label(entrywindow, text="Date of Purchase (YYYY-MM-DD)").grid(row=1, column=0)
    date = StringVar()
    dateentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=date).grid(row=1, column=1)

    deptdisp = Label(entrywindow, text="Name Of Department(s) seperate with ','").grid(row=2, column=0)
    dept = StringVar()
    deptentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=dept).grid(row=2, column=1)

    amtdisp = Label(entrywindow, text="Amount Purchased").grid(row=3, column=0)
    amt = StringVar()
    amtentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=amt).grid(row=3, column=1)

    amt2disp = Label(entrywindow, text="Amount Installed").grid(row=4, column=0)
    amt2 = StringVar()
    amt2entry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=amt2).grid(row=4, column=1)

    labdisp = Label(entrywindow, text="Room number Of Lab(s) seperate with ','").grid(row=5, column=0)
    lab = StringVar()
    labentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=lab).grid(row=5, column=1)

    thrdisp = Label(entrywindow, text="Threshold").grid(row=6, column=0)
    thr = StringVar()
    threntry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=thr).grid(row=6, column=1)

    confirm = Button(entrywindow, text="Confirm", command = makeEntry(name,date,dept,amt,amt2,lab,thr)).grid(row=7, column=0)
    exi = Button(entrywindow, text="Exit", command = entrywindow.destroy).grid(row=7, column=1)

    entryWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you please edit the above code as i can't read it?

Comment: You have executed `makeEntry(...)` when you create the `Confirm` button, so the record inserted will be all empty strings since all the entries have nothing input at that time.  Change it to `command=lambda: makeEntry(...)` instead.

Comment: tried, still throws empty strings.

Comment: Your code works in my environment after using `lambda` and fixing the typo error: `entryWindow.mainloop()` to `entrywindow.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i faced this problem, when you type this line of code for example :

```
labentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=lab).grid(row=5, column=1)
```

The labentry value will be returned as None so try :

```
labentry = Entry(entrywindow, textvariable=lab);labentry.grid(row=5, column=1)
```

Hope i helped you

Comment: It will not change the **blank** thing as he mentioned.

Comment: I've done the same for the username and password and there it works perfectly

Comment: does it works ? if it works change all labels and entry widgets and vote this answer  to earnsome reputation

Comment: you got me wrong, the solution you gave isn't necessary because I've done the former in another code and it worked there so it is of no use to put that semicolon.